# How to ensure Jest fails on "unhandledRejection"?

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

Our unit tests run in containers in our continuous delivery pipelines.

Sometimes, we don't handle rejections in our unit tests, however, I don't think it's correct and in my opinion the pipeline should fail.

How can I make sure that when I execute `jest` and during the tests an `unhandledRejection` event occurs, jest will exit with error?

I tried to hook event listeners in a setup script:

```
/* jest.config.js */
module.exports = {
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/setup.ts'],
    // ...
}
```

and in that setup script, I can detect `unhandledRejection` events, but unfortunately, I can't make jest break

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', () => {
    console.error('Now what?');
    console.error('I want to make sure that jest exits with an error!');
});
```

Comment: `Sometimes, we don't handle rejections in our unit tests, however, I don't think it's correct` -- then explicitly handle the rejections. A unit test that does not handle errors is a bad unit test.

Comment: That's what I want to enforce, however as the pipeline does not break, we need to go through the test output...

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying you have no control over the unit test implementations? If you can write a handler for `process.on('unhandledRejection')`, you should just provide a `.catch()` to all your promises (or `try...catch` for `async` functions) so your pipeline can simply state what caused the failure. `unhandledRejection` should be reserved for asynchronous [boneheaded exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/), which indicates _bugs in your unit tests_ as I originally stated.

Comment: The code is shared among multiple developers and I can't always review the code. My colleagues might not notice a warning in the logs about the unhandled exception, but if I make the unit test fail on one, they will notice it and fix it

Comment: the [unhandleddRejection](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) event also has a `reason` and `promise` parameter which could be useful and should be logged to the console

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create a jest config file `jest.config.js` and put the following entry into it:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/setup.js'],
  ...
};
```

And then in your `setup.js` file, you can do something like this:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
  fail(err);
});
```

And `unhandledRejection` will fail a test, though there are two caveates to be aware of:

1. Unhandled rejections from promises that reject when there is no test running will end the process. This is probably what you want and expect.
2. Unhandled rejections from promises that reject when a new test is running (not the one that initiated the promise) will fail the new test, not the original test. This is confusing and can make for difficult to track bugs.

As a commenter mentioned above, if your tests are well written, then you should never hit this scenario, but you don't always have that much control.

Comment: "if your tests are well written, then you should never hit this scenario" That's exactly the point. I want to add this check to make sure that we don't accidentally miss exceptions while we write our tests. The check is there to ensure we don't mess up the tests.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understand why people feel they don't need a safety net. We write tests because our code may be imperfect, so why do we feel our test code will be perfect?! It baffles me, I'll definitely be adding this to my code in hopes that it never needs to run.

Comment: I had to combine this with `--runInBand` otherwise jest wasn't failing on jest 25.5.4

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following flags when running jest did the trick for me:

```
--detectOpenHandles --forceExit --runInBand
```

Comment: Hm, for me it didn't detect unhandled rejections, but instead of this, it complained about "localStorage.setItem" lines, because of possible timeouts inside the jsDOM's local storage implementation. I ended up removing these flags.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @andrew-eisenberg answer, you can also config setup file in package.json as follows:

```
"jest": {
  ...
  "setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/../test/setup.ts"],
  ...
}
```

src [doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration)