# How to test status of a promise inside Promise.finally() without awaiting it in production code

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs, try-catch-finally

I am using [Promise.prototype.finally()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) (or try-catch-finally in an `async` function) in my production code to execute some follow-up code without changing resolution/rejection status of the current promise.

However, in my Jest tests, I would like to **detect that the Promise inside finally block wasn't rejected**.

*edit*: But I don't want to actually await the Promise in my "production" code (there I care only about errors re-thrown from catch, but not about errors from finally).

How can I test for that? Or at least how to mock the Promise.prototype to reject the current promise on exceptions from finally?

E.g. if I would be testing `redux` action creators, the tests pass even though there is a message about an unhandled Promise rejection:

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-dijkstra-nbcno?file=/src/index.test.js

```js
test("finally", async () => {
  const actions = await dispatchMock(add("forgottenParent", { a: 1 }));
  const newState = actions.reduce(reducer, undefined);
  expect(newState).toEqual({});
});

const dispatchMock = async thunk => {...};

// ----- simplified "production" code -----

const reducer = (state = {}, action) => state;
const add = parentId => async dispatch => {
  dispatch("add start");
  try {
    await someFetch("someData");
    dispatch("add success");
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch("add failed");
    throw e;
  } finally {
    dispatch(get(parentId)); // tests pass if the promise here is rejected
  }
};
const get = id => async dispatch => {
  dispatch("get start");
  try {
    await someFetch(id);
    dispatch("get success");
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch("get failed");
    throw e;
  }
};
const someFetch = async id => {
  if (id === "forgottenParent") {
    throw new Error("imagine I forgot to mock this request");
  }
  Promise.resolve(id);
};
```

Comment: Are you saying an exception is thrown inside `get` or inside `dispatch`?

Comment: If an exception is thrown inside a `finally` in both normal (synchronous) and `async`/`await` (not when using Promise method chaining) the exception *should* be re-thrown at the top-level `await` unless it was swallowed somewhere in-between. If you are seeing exceptions being silently swallowed, I suggest using the "Break on all thrown exceptions" (or similarly-named option) in your JavaScript debugger. By default most JS debuggers only break for _unhandled_/uncaught exceptions. Hopefully that way you can see where it gets caught and swallowed.

Comment: @Dai it's re-thrown inside `get`'s catch block by `throw e`. and no no no, it's working as per specification, exceptions from inside `finally` are ignored as far as the resolved status of the outer Promise is concerned => it's swallowed by the `finally` itself and that is correct behaviour (but I want to change that behaviour inside my tests) - see the "tests" tab and "Problems" sub-tab when executing on linked codesandbox

Comment: just to be clear, the exception **is** re-thrown at the top level. but it does not reject the promise and it does not make the async test fail

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> dispatch(get(parentId)); // tests pass if an exception is thrown here
> ```

There is no exception throw in that line. `get(parentId)` might return a rejected promise (or a pending promise that will get rejected later), but that's not an exception and won't affect control flow.

You might be looking for

```
const add = parentId => async dispatch => {
  dispatch("add start");
  try {
    await someFetch("someData");
    dispatch("add success");
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch("add failed");
    throw e;
  } finally {
    await dispatch(get(parentId));
//  ^^^^^
  }
};
```

Notice that [throwing exceptions from a `finally` block is not exactly a best practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/188858/66652) though.

Comment: awaiting a rejected promise in finally does not change the already resolved outer Promise... I know it's not a best practice, that's why I want to test that it does NOT happen => I need the test to fail if it happens

Comment: @Aprillion I cannot reproduce. `async function example() { try { throw new Error("inner"); } finally { await Promise.reject(new Error("outer")); } }` will definitely reject with the outer error and ignore the inner one.

Comment: no throw inside `try` plz - `async function example() { try { return 1 } finally { await Promise.reject(new Error("outer")); } }`

Comment: I want to make an assertion about the Promise from finally...

Comment: @Aprillion Doesn't matter what the `try` block does - it always throws the `outer` error from `finally` and rejects `example()` even when you `return 1;`

Comment: hm, maybe Jest is doing something nonstandard.. tests in codesandbox do not work for me at the moment - I will get back if I manage to update my example

Comment: ok, tested locally and you were right - I just missed an `await` inside finally - it needs to be outside of `dispatch` for my tests to work because my `dispatchMock` is async. thanks!

Comment: dammit...  awaiting inside finally changes the business logic :(( I don't want to reject the promise in "production" code - only in the test code.

Comment: I found a solution (posted as an answer), thank you for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

**edit**: more general solutions available on https://stackoverflow.com/a/58634792/1176601

---

It is possible to store the Promise in a variable accessible in some helper function that is used only for the tests, e.g.:

```
export const _getPromiseFromFinallyInTests = () => _promiseFromFinally
let _promiseFromFinally

const add = parentId => async dispatch => {
  ...
  } finally {
    // not awaited here because I don't want to change the current Promise
    _promiseFromFinally = dispatch(get(parentId));
  }
};
```

and update the test to await the test-only Promise:

```
test("finally", async () => {
  ...
  // but I want to fail the test if the Promise from finally is rejected
  await _getPromiseFromFinallyInTests()
});
```